# How to write a raster file with our color palette on hard drive?

Tags: r, colors, raster, tiff, color-palette

I have a Raster file (its name: My_Gray_Scale_Raster.tif ). Here is the Tiff file download link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/i2xig52flkr5bc6/My_Gray_Scale_Raster.tif?dl=1

using this R script I can read it in R:

```
setwd("F:/back19")
list_tiff <- raster(list.files(getwd(), pattern = "My_Gray_Scale_Raster.tif$", recursive = TRUE))
list_tiff
```

So, I can see it has 7 values: 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , and 6.

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 420, 275, 115500  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 500, 500  (x, y)
extent      : 422447.3, 559947.3, 6029253, 6239253  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=12 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
data source : F:/back19/My_Gray_Scale_Raster.tif 
names       : My_Gray_Scale_Raster 
values      : 0, 6  (min, max)
```

I want to assign 7 colors to each of these values, like:

```
my_clo <- c("#009a1d" , "#3934ff" , "#faff34" ,  "#e62c00",  "#9f34ff", "#ff9f34", "#34ffd2" )
```

And finally, write/create a new Raster file on hard drive WITH my color palette. So, if anyone opens the new Raster file in ArcGIS, he/she sees the Raster file in my desired color palette.

I googled and read many things on the net, but all of them were talking about Plot() the Raster inside R, rather than save a new Raster file with the color palette.

Any comments would be highly appreciated.